# How to get all site using PnP PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'd like to get All site in SharePoint Online via PnP Powershell

I was able to get all sitecollection URL via Get-PnPTenantSite Commandlet .

However I don't know Howto get Site Object using PnP PowerShell.

I tryed this but didn't work

```
$sites = Get-PnPTenantSite

 foreach($site in $sites){
Get-PnPsite -Url  $site.url
}
```

Anyone Know how to get all site via PnP PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

Use this SharePoint Online PnP PowerShell to Get All Sites：

```
#Set Parameter
$TenantSiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com"
 
#Connect to the Tenant site
Connect-PnPOnline $TenantSiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#sharepoint online pnp powershell get all sites
Get-PnPTenantSite
```

Reference:[https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/get-all-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20get%20all,subsites](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/get-all-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html#:%7E:text=How%20do%20I%20get%20all,subsites))